# Override time field on Django admin

Tags: python, django, date, django-admin

I have a model that contains some events. The event has a start_time_unix and a local_timezone.

I am using the Django Admin panel to allow the user to set the event start_time_unix in the local_timezone of that event. To do this, I overrode the `save` function of the model to convert this to UTC and save in the database.

My question is, how can I make it convert to the local timezone of that event when it is viewed through the Admin model form? Currently it displays in UTC. I think I need to override the DateTimeField or something, but my attempts so far have not been successful.

Comment: So, as an example, you want a user to select an event's time using EST, have the database store it in UTC, then have the admin see it in EST?

Comment: @tsroten exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable time zone support and remove your customized `save` function logic.

[Django's Documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores date and time information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

From the same documentation page, we can see how to enable time zone support:

> Time zone support is disabled by default. To enable it, set [`USE_TZ = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_TZ) in your settings file. Installing [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is highly recommended, but not mandatory. It’s as simple as:
>
> ```
> $ sudo pip install pytz
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have `USE_TZ = True`, the problem is that is for the users timezone, whereas these model objects have their own timezone independent of the user timezone.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Since you already have the ``save`` function logic taken care of, you just need to to take care of the value that is initially displayed. That is done by the ``initial`` attribute of the form field. In the form's ``__init__`` function, change the ``DateTimeField``'s (or whatever field you're using) ``initial`` attribute to the correct timezone. Then, the form will display it correctly.

Comment: Because this answer didn't address the issue at all, I've submitted another answer that should directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your form's code, you'll want to change the initial display value of the time field in the `__init__` function:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_initial = self.fields['date_time'].initial
        self.fields['date_time'].initial = _to_local_time_zone(current_initial)

    def _to_local_time_zone(date_time):
        """Changes a datetime object's timezone."""
        pass

    date_time = forms.DateTimeField(....)

    ....
```

An alternative strategy would be to change it in the `data` keyword argument before passing that on up to `forms.ModelForm.__init__`:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            data, args = args[0], args[1:]
        else:
            data = kwargs.pop('data', None)
        if data and 'date_time' in data:
            # Make a copy because QueryDict objects are immutable.
            data = data.copy()
            utc_date_time = data['date_time']
            data['date_time'] = self._to_local_time_zone(utc_date_time)

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

    def _to_local_time_zone(date_time):
        """Changes a datetime object's timezone."""
        pass

    date_time = forms.DateTimeField(....)

    ....
```

Comment: Yet another idea, is to change it in the template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone